# How to prove the vector calculus identity using divergence theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of the following lemma:

**Lemma**. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with primitive $G(u)=\int_{0}^{u} g(v) d v$ and let $u \in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap C^{1}(\bar{\Omega})$ be a solution of the equation

$$
-\Delta u=g(u) \quad \text { in } \Omega,\quad \ (1.5)
$$
$$
u=0 \quad \text { on } \partial \Omega,\quad \quad  (1.6)
$$
in a domain $\Omega \subset \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} .$ Then there holds
$$
\frac{n-2}{2} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2} d x-n \int_{\Omega} G(u) d x+\frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial \Omega}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right|^{2} x \cdot \nu d S=0
$$
where $\nu$ denotes the exterior unit normal.

**Proof Attempt**: The author proceeds by multiplying $x\cdot \nabla u$ to the equation (1.5) to get,
\begin{aligned}
0=(\Delta u&+g(u))(x \cdot \nabla u) \\
&=\operatorname{div}(\nabla u(x \cdot \nabla u))-|\nabla u|^{2}-x \cdot \nabla\left(\frac{|\nabla u|^{2}}{2}\right)+x \cdot \nabla G(u) \\
&=\operatorname{div}\left(\nabla u(x \cdot \nabla u)-x \frac{|\nabla u|^{2}}{2}+x G(u)\right)+\frac{n-2}{2}|\nabla u|^{2}-n G(u)
\end{aligned}
Now here is the part that I don't understand. The author says that since $u=0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ we have,
$$x\cdot \nabla u = (x\cdot \nu) \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}.$$
I don't know understand why we can make this assumption. Furthermore if we assume that this is true then why does,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial \Omega} \left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right|^2 x\cdot \nu dS = \int_{\Omega} \operatorname{div}\left(\nabla u(x \cdot \nabla u)-x \frac{|\nabla u|^{2}}{2}+x G(u)\right)dx.
\end{align}
I am guessing this is an application of the divergence theorem and that $G(u)=0$ since $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega.$ But I don't understand how the other two terms are maniupulated to the get the expression. Any comments/suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You refer to "the author" a couple times. While someone may be able to answer without this information, it would be helpful to provide the context of the book or notes you are looking at.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does "$\subset\subset$" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now here is the part that I don't understand. The author says that since $u=0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ we have,
> $$x\cdot \nabla u = (x\cdot \nu) \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}.$$
> I don't know understand why we can make this assumption.

At a point $p\in\partial\Omega$, we can choose an orthonormal basis with the unit vector $\nu$ normal to $\partial\Omega$ as one of the basis vectors. All the other basis vectors $\omega_i$ point along $\partial\Omega$. But $u$ is constant on $\partial\Omega$, so $\frac {\partial u}{\partial \omega_i} = 0$. Now as with any orthonormal basis,
$$\nabla u = \dfrac {\partial u}{\partial \nu}\nu + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \omega_i}\omega_i = \dfrac {\partial u}{\partial \nu}\nu$$

And after applying the divergence theorem, you will find from using this same representation of $\nabla u$, that the first two terms have the same value on the boundary, except for the $-\frac 12$ coefficient.

Comment: Just to clarify you are evaluating the gradient at point $p$ right?

Comment: Yes, everything is evaluated at the same point $p$. However, there is a similar equation for each point on the boundary. The basis $\{\nu_p\}\cup \{\omega_{pi}\}_{i=1}^{n-1}$ changes from point to point, but the equation looks the same.

Comment: I was revisiting your answer, would it be correct to say that the basis vectors $\omega_i$ lie in the tangent space of $\Omega$?

Comment: Technically yes, but since $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ (I guess - you never did answer my question about the doubled subset symbol), all the tangent spaces are naturally isomophic to $\Bbb R^n$ as a vector space, so usually one just uses vector calculus instead of differential geometry to discuss it.